# cannot receive notification from Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: python, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

i want to send push notification to my device with **Firebase Cloud Messaging**, everything is fine while using **Firebase Composer** panel, i can send and receive **Messages** through **composer**, but when i want to do it with python, i don't receive any Message on my device though The response says that Message sent successfully  , here is my code:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import datetime
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import messaging
from firebase_admin import credentials
        

def send_to_token():
    # [START send_to_token]
    # This registration token comes from the client FCM SDKs.
    registration_token = 'my-android-device-registration-token'

    # See documentation on defining a message payload.
    message = messaging.Message(
        data={
            'score': '850',
            'time': '2:45',
        },
        token=registration_token
    )

    # Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
    # registration token.
    response = messaging.send( message)
    # Response is a message ID string.
    print('Successfully sent message:', response)
    # [END send_to_token]

if not firebase_admin._apps:
    cred = credentials.Certificate('google.json') 
    default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

send_to_token()
```

and it gives me this response that indicates successful operation:

> projects/app-name/messages/0:1650xxxxx4999573%4bf3b6xxxxxd7ecd

but i don't receive any notification on my device and i cant find the problem.

so where is my problem? is it in my code?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research, actually, there is an USSD code that you can run and see your notification log, if they arrived or not arrived at all, at the end the problem was related to the android application signing in the firebase app panel, after signing it properly the problem had been solved.